# How to configure htaccess to work with many projects on codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, svn, project

Im starting a project with codeigniter and need to configure the .htaccess file to redirect the url.

My directories:

```
-/backend
 |-  /applications
 |-  /system
 |-  /assets


-/frontend
  |-  /application
  |-  /system
  |-  /assets
```

.htaccess file needs to run like

```
/admin/(.*) to /backend/index.php/$1
/(.*) to /frontend/index.php/$1
```

I've tried something like this but seems that codeigniter do not recognize info that comes after.
Like:
`/admin/access/login or /admin/access/verify`
It appears on address bar correctly but it keeps returning the result from controller access/index

I need this structure because I'm working with SVN and need the directories to be separated.

Does anyone had this problem too ?

Comment: Put the `/admin/(.*) to /backend/index/$1` at the first.

Comment: It is already first... i´ve switched the order on post

Comment: You're missing .php extension in your /admin/ rewrite rule.

Comment: i forgot to write down the extension... the problem persists